# What files in my Rails project are not safe to commit to a public repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

For example, secret_token.rb should not be included. Are there others like this? I plan on starting a new Rails 4 app soon, and I'd like to make it completely open source.

Answer (score 1):

You should not include any db/api keys/passwords/tokens, but this is simple - just store them in ENV variables (but remember to specify that in readme).
As for Rails there's no other file that should really be kept secret.

Comment: database.yml, then? Or are you saying not to use database.yml at all?

Comment: Depends. I don't really know why you want to release a Rails app instead of making a gem using mountable engine for instance.

Comment: A lot of people I know have wondered if there were good, open source Rails apps that they could learn from. There are only a few, sadly. I'd like to use my app as an example for my co-workers (and anyone else), and hopefully get feedback from other people on how my code could improve.

Comment: I don't really get your point. Rails guides are excellent introduction and in-depth view of various parts of Rails. Then you have RailsCasts which look onto specific features/gems/problems. Do you relly think that writing a sample app will help anyone to learn to code?

Comment: Yes, it would have helped me a ton.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248371/good-open-source-ruby-on-rails-projects-to-learn-from Looks like it is a pretty popular request :]